# Regex Match Resolution with High Bandwidth from Master m3u8 file

Tags: c#, m3u8

I'm having a little problem with matching the highest bandwidth from m3u8 master file

Here's the content of master.m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=149000,RESOLUTION=320x180,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://testurl 1
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=300000,RESOLUTION=320x180,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://testurl 2
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=500000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://testurl 3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=800000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://testurl 4
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1000000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://testurl 5
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1299000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://testurl 6
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1499000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://testurl 7
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=62000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://testurl 8
```

I'm able to get the url by resolution. But the problem is some of the master m3u8 has three url with the same resolution but different bandwidth.

My goal is, if I choose 1280x720 and if there will be multiple result with the same resolution, I want to get only the url with the highest bandwidth like in the example content. the highest is 1499000

Here's my current code.

```
private static void TEST()
{
var f = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\MARK\Desktop\TEST\master.m3u8");
    
string result = string.Empty;
    
    result = ParseM3u8Master(f, "1280x720", 2);
    if (result == "") {
        result = ParseM3u8Master(f, "640x360", 2);
    }else if (result == ""){
        result = ParseM3u8Master(f, "320x180", 2);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

private const RegexOptions ML = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline;
public static string ParseM3u8Master(string m3u8Master, string resolution, int group)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    string pattern = $@"(?:RESOLUTION=({resolution}).*?)\n(https.+|http[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=])";
    if (Regex.IsMatch(m3u8Master, pattern, ML))
    {
        result = Regex.Match(m3u8Master, pattern, ML).Groups[group].Value;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You'll probably have a better time parsing this line by line, splitting each `#EXT-X-STREAM-INF` to key-value pairs and storing them in e.g. a dictionary you associate with the URL.

Comment: I actually solved already. I'll update with my solution. But maybe there's more better solution than mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: (After trying to figure out the solution. I got successfully get the highest bandwidth which is always at the last)

Here's my solution (maybe you can suggest better than this)

```
private const RegexOptions ML = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline;
public static string ParseM3u8Master(string m3u8Master, string resolution, int group)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    string pattern = $@"(?:RESOLUTION=({resolution}).*?)\n(https.+|http[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=])";
    if (Regex.IsMatch(m3u8Master, pattern, ML))
    {
        var lst = new List<string>();
        var mc = Regex.Matches(m3u8Master, pattern, ML); 
        foreach (Match m in mc) {
            lst.Add(m.Groups[2].Value);
        }
        result = lst.Last();
    }
    return res
}
```